# ADL xapi launch

Tags: tin-can-api, xapi

I currently try to understand how the adl launch algorithm works. I've found the great tutorial by ht2labs (https://github.com/LearningLocker/xapi-demos) and the corresponding videos (https://vimeo.com/272792141 and https://vimeo.com/272792152). The tutorial shows which data are required by the launch-server to generate the xAPILaunchKey, but not, how it's generated. Could someone explain, how I can generate a valid xAPILaunchKey?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that ADL has archived the xAPI launch repo (https://github.com/adlnet/xapi-launch) and AFAIK it is basically DOA. There is very little (if any) adoption in the wild and you are better off considering cmi5 for xAPI based launch.

Comment: @Brian Thanks for the reply. Indeed, I considered to use cmi5. Unfortunately, the framework I use for creating my e-learning courses (ADAPT Framework) does not support cmi5.